# Does a set of all real valued functions form group under componentwise multiplication?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions

I think I have verified the first two axioms: closure, associativity.
For existence of identity, I said that $\forall$ $f$ $\in$ $\mathbb R^\mathbb R$, there is a function $e(x) = 1$ $\in$ $\mathbb R^\mathbb R$ s.t. $f.e = f = e.f$.

How do I show existence of inverse though? So, for example if I have $f(x) = x$, what would be the inverse under componentwise multiplication? Initially, I though simply $\frac{1}{x}$ might do the job, or in general for any $f$ simply its reciprocal function should be the inverse. But, what if there are some values in $\mathbb R$ where the inverse is not even defined. For e.g. $f(x) = x$ is defined for $x = 0$, but $\frac{1}{x}$ is not defined at $x=0$. Can someone help me see what is going on?

Comment: I think your argument shows why some elements do not have an inverse.

Comment: It is similar to the groups $\bmod p$ for $p$ prime.  They form a group under addition and the non-zero elements form a group under multiplication.  The functions $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R\setminus 0$ form a group under componentwise multiplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly. So this set is not a group. You gave an example of a function which has a problem at one point. I can give you an example where things are much worse: how about the function $f\equiv 0$? So it is not a group.

Now, you can look at the set of real valued functions $f$ such that $f(x)\ne 0$ for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Now this is a group with respect to multiplication of functions as you can easily check.

Comment: Unfortunately, the question I am trying explicitly asks us to prove that the set of all real-valued functions denoted as $\mathbb R ^\mathbb R$ forms a group under componentwise structure.

Comment: @Ufomammut:  you can't prove it because it isn't true.

Comment: @RossMillikan haha true that. I was not trying to insist that it should be true.

Comment: Then I guess the exercise is wrong.

Comment: @Ufomammut if it wasn’t specified then the operation is presumably addition, as the real numbers are a group under this operation, and group valued functions on any nonempty set form a group under componentwise operations.

Comment: Well, maybe I just don't understand what componentwise structure means here. If it is addition then everything is fine.